# Cómo puedo mejorar el buscador de mi app react,js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, busqueda

tengo una app en react.js a la cual le he agregado un buscador interno de la siguiente manera:

```
    function Search({ details }) {

  const [searchField, setSearchField] = useState("");

  const filteredProducts = details.filter(
    product => {
      return (
        product
        .title
        .toLowerCase()
        .includes(searchField.toLowerCase()) ||
        product
        .description
        .toLowerCase()
        .includes(searchField.toLowerCase())
      );
    }
  );

  const handleChange = e => {
    setSearchField(e.target.value);
  };

  function searchList() {
    return (
        <SearchList filteredProducts={filteredProducts} />
    );
  }
```

me gustaría que al buscar por titulo, tome la búsqueda desde el principio, porque por ejemplo si busco "GArbarino", también me muestra "fraveGA, ya que las 2 palabras tienen "GA", solamente quisiera que se muestre GArbarino que es por donde empieza y lo que la gente buscaría. Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplemente tienes que reemplazar el método `includes` por `startsWith`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith

Pero puedes mejorar más tu buscador haciendo que ignore los acentos u otros caracteres especiales. De esa forma, si tienes un producto como *Brócoli* el usuario podrá encontrarlo tanto si escribe `Bro` como `Bró`.

Para hacerlo necesitas una función que elimine los signos diacríticos (áñç..) transformando los caracteres en su versión sin modificar (anc..). Lo más fácil es usar los [Escapes de propiedades Unicode](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Unicode_Property_Escapes): Primero normalizando la cadena a unicode y luego reemplazando los caracteres diacríticos por los "originales" (https://unicode.org/reports/tr44/#Diacritic).

```js
console.log('áéíóúñç'.normalize("NFD").replace(/\p{Diacritic}/gu, ""))
// output: aeiounc
```

Con todo esto tu código podría quedar así:

```js
  function removeDiacritic(texto) {
    return texto.toLowerCase().normalize("NFD").replace(/\p{Diacritic}/gu, ""))
  }


  const filteredProducts = details.filter(product => {
    const searchParam = removeDiacritic(searchField)

    return (
      removeDiacritic(product.title).startsWith(searchParam) 
      ||
      removeDiacritic(product.description).startsWith(searchParam) 
      );
    }
  );
```

Comment: Buenas tardes, muchisimas gracias! Me sirvió completamente. Un saludo